# "like the game" vs "like the sport"

Tags: word-choice

(1) Jack asked me, "Do you play hockey?" I replied, "I do because I like the game."

(2) Jack asked me, "Do you play hockey?" I replied, "I do because I like the sport."

I usually hear people say "like the game". Is it wrong to say "like the sport"?

Comment: They both sound alright to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "the game" and "the sport" are pretty much interchangeable in the context of your example - the sport of hockey.

"Sport" may sound slightly more professional than "game" - for example, kids can play a game of football and not take it too seriously, but to 'take up a sport' means to begin playing it more seriously, either as part of a personal regime or even professionally.

Also, just as many 'games' are not considered sports (for example, board games), some things are considered a sport, but are not a 'game', for example, fishing.